# QMainWindow is handling event that should be caught by QDialog

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QMainWindow with an event filter installed that opens a QDialog.
The main window handles the key release of the Enter key.
But, when I press the Enter key while the QDialog is open and in focus the main window also catches this event.

How can I prevent that from happening?
I tried to install an event filter in the QDialog, to reimplement the keyReleaseEvent and keyPressEvent functions, change the parent (which is currently 0), but nothing seems to help...

Note that when I change the event filter of the QMainWindow such that it handles key press instead of key release the QDialog works fine, but then I get other bugs that I'm trying to avoid...

```
bool Window::eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *event) {
 if (type == QEvent::KeyRelease) {
   QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);

   switch(keyEvent->key()) {
   case Qt::Key_Enter:
     // do something here
     break;
   default:
     break;
   }
}

Dialog::Dialog(unsigned int num, QWidget *parent)
: QDialog(parent), num(_num)
{
   ui.setupUi(this);
   ui.btnOK->setEnabled(false);

   connect(ui.btnOK, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(accept()));
   connect(ui.btnCancel, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(reject()));

   installEventFilter(this);
}

bool Dialog::eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *event) {
 return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try webclectic's first approach, but replace `e->ignore()` with `e->accept()`, since `ignore()`'s behaviour is opposite to what you want to achieve.

```
void MyDialog::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent* e)
{
    QDialog::keyReleaseEvent(e);
    if (e->key() == Qt::Key_Enter)
        e->accept();
}
```

Or maybe you should try modal dialog?

**UPDATE:** We must always call QDialog's implementation if we want the dialog to respond to Enter key release.

Comment: It doesn't matter if he uses `accept` or `ignore` since the event will be propagated only in the else statement. Since the receiver does not want the event the `ignore` function should be used (for code readiness)

Comment: As far as I know, it does matter, because QDialog::keyReleaseEvent(e) have no control over the event dispatcher. It just checks keycodes for return/esc and triggers accept()/reject() if it has to, and returns event back to dispatcher where the propagation takes place. Am I wrong?

Comment: Dmitriy is correct, calling `QDialog::keyReleaseEvent()` just allows the base class's implementation of this function to be executed, it has nothing to do with whether or not the event is propagated. Otherwise there would be no need for the accept/ignore functions to even exist.